# Convert timestamp to date in Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, date, group-by, pivot-table, excel-2016

I have a pivot table which currently looks like this:

```
                                  No of Sales  
 Team 1
     2017-03-10T07:10:20.289Z     1
     2017-03-10T07:10:22.289Z     4
     2017-03-14T07:08:20.289Z     10

 Team 2
     2017-03-11T07:14:20.289Z     11
```

I want to group by the date in the timestamp and only show the date and the total for that day so it looks like this instead:

```
                                  No of Sales  
 Team 1
     2017-03-10                   5
     2017-03-14                   10

 Team 2
     2017-03-11                   11
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to use helper columns to convert the date in excel?

Answer (score 0):

you can do the rest of the code, but the important part is:

```
strTemp= cells(row, col).value 'this contains the date 2017-03-10T07:10:20.289Z 

strDate = split(strTemp, "T")(0)
```

That's it.